# One fourth of the screen does not respond: Kubuntu 16.04 VM

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, kubuntu, screen, plasma

I am using Kubuntu 16.04 through the Oracle VM manager. After a while after launching the VM, the part of the screen (shown on the figure below) stops responding to any mouth events. I am not sure if it happens because of the specific action I perform; everything seems to be pretty usual.
[image: Unreponsive part of the screen]

I have tried to use a script to restart Plasma:

```
#!/bin/bash

killall plasmashell

plasmashell &
```

However, after restarting, the screen still does not respond.

So, what do you think is a problem here? How can I solve it?

Comment: FYI: Kubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Kubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks, are offline, or use Ubuntu's default Unity desktop (*which still is supported*).